# How to add js condition to know if this is the first traffic in last n minutes

Tags: javascript, html

Please i am trying to make a JS code to redirect user if this is the first traffic in last n minutes and if not just click a button in the page and i have written a script to do that but i just donnot know what is the condition which state if this is the first traffic so anyone can help ? and if this is not possible anyone has an idea how to do that using JS

```
if (condition) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.exapmle.com";
} else {
    document.getElementById('button-login').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could approach this with cookies and set an expiration date, but it might behave oddly, since some browsers/browser versions handle cookies differently.

If you are using vanilla Javascript, defer your script tag (read about the defer property if it's new to you), like this:

```
<script defer src="./myScriptFile.js"></script>
```

Check for the cookie, do what you have to do and then set it again. Your script file should look like this:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

function setLastAccess() {
  const date = new Date();
  const expireMs = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 minutes
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + expireMs);
  document.cookie = `lastAccess=${new Date().getTime()};expires=${date.toUTCString()};path=/`;
}


if(!getCookie('lastAccess')) {
  // do what have you have to do when last access was before 5 minutes ago or it's the first access
  setLastAccess(); // set your last access at the end
} else {
  // this will run when last access was not before 5 minutes ago
}
```

Comment: First thanks for you help and your time but i want to let you know that i use the js code in the same html file not a external js file and i use this tag <script type="text/javascript" ></script> so is this a problem

Comment: you might have to place the script from the <head> to <body> and check if there's any different result